# How to prevent re-renders of nested navigators in react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, optimization, react-navigation

Lets say we have nested navigators like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <RootStack.Navigator>
    <RootStack.Screen name="Sceen" component={Screen} />
    <RootStack.Screen name="MainApp" component={MainApp} />
  </RootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

// Main app
<MainTabs.Navigator>
  <MainTabs.Screen name="NestedStack" component={NestedStack} />
  <MainTabs.Screen name="AnotherScreen" component={AnotherScreen} />
</MainTabs.Navigator>

// NestedStack
<NestedStack.Navigator>
  <NestedStack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
  <NestedStack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
</NestedStack.Navigator>
```

Now, if we navigate from `Screen1` to `Screen2`, it seems the whole tree right from `NavigationContainer` re-renders. It slows down screen transition a lot. Is it possible to prevent the whole tree re-render and re-render only the `NestedStack`?

Comment: Impossible to say what causes the re renders when only seeing the jsx. Are the components functional components, are they pure, why is the parent re rendered? Maybe you can provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that no external hook/prop/state change is causing the re-render. This is probably how react-navigation works. I wanted to know if that can be changed.

Comment: @S.j.Sakib did you find any solution to this? I am also having a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746377/stacknavigator-inside-bottomtabnavigator-is-re-rendered-when-navigating-screens