# StackNavigator inside BottomTabNavigator is re-rendered when navigating screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a `Tab Navigator`. The `Tabs` contain `Stack Navigators`.

The structure of the code is:

```
Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
SettingStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen(){
  return //some JSX
};

function ProfileScreen(){
  return //some JSX
};

function SettingScreen(){
  return //some JSX
};

function MyStack(){

  //
  *********************** THIS_SEGMENT ****************************
  //

  return(
   <HomeStack.Navigator>
     <HomeStack.Screen component={HomeScreen} />
     <HomeStack.Screen component={ProfileScreen} />
   </HomeStack.Navigator>
  )
}

function SettingStackScreen(){
  return(
   <SettingStack.Navigator>
     <SettingStack.Screen component={SettingScreen} />
   </SettingStack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen component={MyStack} />
        <Tab.Screen component={SettingStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The problem is whenever I navigate between `HomeScreen` and `ProfileScreen`,  `THIS_SEGMENT` is executed.

I don't want to execute the `THIS_SEGMENT` part when switching between the two screens.

This is the link to snack showing my problem: https://snack.expo.io/@vipulchandra04/nested-stacknavigator
. In `line-41` message is logged when switching between `HomeScreen` and `ProfileScreen`.

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem, but every Navigator.Screen should have a unique 'name' prop. Can you try that?

Comment: @PedroFeltrin Yes, I have included 'name' in the actual code(see snack link). This is just pseudo code.